# Come up with this function

Tags: functions

Here's a fun math question:

Come up with a function where 
$$
\begin{align}
g''(1) &= 0 \\
g(0) &= 0 \\
g'(0) &= 0 \\
g(1) &= 1 \\
g'(1) &= 1
\end{align}
$$

I've tried multiple variations of cosine/sine/tan/arctan, exponential, logarithmic, cubics, and have done shifts and can not seem to get all these conditions to satisfy.

Comment: Multiple variations of cosine/sine/tan/arctan, exponential, logarithmic, cubics, and have done shifts and can not seem to get all these conditions to satisfy

Comment: Ok, thats a start. Try to use a polynomial of degree 4. Then you have 5 unknowns and 5 equations to be satisfied...

Comment: @sranthrop I tried and I can not get the f''(1) = 0 condition :/

Comment: I have done it for you in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f(x):=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$. Then $f'(x)=4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d$ and $f''(x)=12ax^2+6bx+2c$. Then we have to solve the system
$12a+6b+2c=0, e=0, d=0, a+b+c+d+e=1, 4a+3b+2c+d=1$, which has the unique solution $a=1,b=-3,c=3,d=0,e=0$. So we have $f(x)=x^4-3x^3+3x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Piecewise you could make the function be $g(x)=x$ for $x>0.5$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\leq0.5$ as you don't state any rules about the function not being able to be a composition or continuous other than at 0 and 1 really.

Comment: Sorry, on [0,1]

Comment: Update the question please as well as state what you want here as my function is defined over the Reals with a point of discontinuity at .5

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to even make sense if the function is defined on $[0,1].$ I mean: $\lim_{x \to 0^-}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 1^+}g(x)$ aren't defined?

Answer (score 0):

$$g(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    0 & : x < 0.5\\
    x & : x \ge 0.5  \end{array}
\right.
$$